# My application calls route.get after route.post executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can not understand how going on there.

`login.js` is route script. Using `login.js` code is included in `app.js`.

The flow what I want to do is below.

1. connect to `localhost:3000/login` -> `route.get('/',...)` is called
2. Check login info.
3. Send the info to `router.post('/loginCheck,...)`
4. If login info is correct, render main page `res.render('main')`

But below is not expected flow I can not understand.

1. connect to `localhost:3000/login` -> `route.get('/',...)` is called
2. Check login info
3. Send the info to `router.post('/loginCheck,...)`
4. If login info is correct, render main page `res.render('main')`
5. The flow goes into `route.get('/',...)` and `res.render('login')` is re-executed.

I can't understand why the flow go into `route.get('/',...)` after `router.post('/loginCheck,...)` end, eventhough there is any code calling `route.get('/',...)`

**Server side :**

```js
//app.js

'use strict';

/******************
 * Declare global variables *
 *******************/
global.__base = __dirname + "/src";
global.__root = __dirname;

/******************
 * Call libraries *
 ******************/
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Logger = require(__base + '/lib/util/logger');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


/******************
 * Milddleware Configuration*
 ******************/
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__root + '/public'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views', __root + '/views');


/******************
 * Environment Configuration *
 ******************/
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

/******************
 * Use router in express *
 ******************/
const main = require(__root + '/routes/main');
const login = require(__root + '/routes/login');

app.use("/main", main);
app.use("/login", login);

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    Logger.info(`connection complete. Open page localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

```js
    //login.js
    
    /****************************************
     * Call libraries *
     ****************************************/
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const mysql = require(__base + '/lib/db/async-mysql');
    const Logger = require(__base + '/lib/util/logger');


    /****************************************
     * Declare Classes *
     ****************************************/
    const CHECK_LOGIN_INFO_SQL = require(__root + '/template/sql/checkLoginInfo').CHECK_LOGIN_INFO

    /****************************************
     * router posts/gets *
     ****************************************/
    const binder = [];

    router.post('/loginCheck', async function (req,res){
        const id = req.body.id;
        const pw = req.body.pw;
        let result = false;

        binder.push(id);

        // res.render('main');
        const sqlResult = await mysql.query(CHECK_LOGIN_INFO_SQL,binder);

        if(sqlResult[0].PW){
            if(sqlResult[0].PW == pw){
                // result = true;
                res.render('main',function(err, html) {
                    console.log('error : ' + err);
                });
            }
        }
    });

    router.get('/', function(req,res){
        console.log('login page open')
        res.render('login');
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

**Client side :**

```js
/******************
 * Login page send post *
 ******************/
const HOST_LOGIN = "/login";
service.checkLogin = function(params) {
    service._sendJsonToServer(HOST_LOGIN+'/loginCheck', 'json', params, function(data){
        //task after ajax success
    });
};



/******************
 * Ajax template *
 ******************/
service._sendJsonToServer = function(url, dataType, params,callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : JSON.stringify(params),
        dataType : dataType,
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/' + dataType,
        // error : errorHandler,
        success: callback
    });
};
```

Comment: How do you "send the info" to /loginCheck ?

Comment: @TGrif  I addied client side code. It is sending data with ajax and I checked that part was find.